# Div pass over other div in transition left/right

Tags: jquery, css

I have a problem with my HTML 5 application. I want to produce a sliding menu (responsive) with a left/right transition where the first panel is always visible for 100px on the right.

But there is a problem. First `<div>` pass over original `<div>`...

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myContainer">
    <div class="animate1 animate1-nomove">
        <section class="myPanel panel-padding">new new new new new</section>
    </div>
    <div class="animate2 animate2-nomove">
        <section class="myPanel panel-padding" id="scrolling">original</section>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#myContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px; right: 0; bottom: 60px; left: 0;
    /* need for sliding menu */
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid;
}

div.animate1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #c00;
    -webkit-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
}

div.animate2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: 2s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
}


/* no move */
.animate1-nomove {left: -100%;}
.animate2-nomove {left: 0px;}

/* move */
.animate1-move {left: 0px; margin-right: 100px;}
.animate2-move {left: 100%; margin-left: -100px;}
```

My fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nKtC6/714/

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are trying to do ?

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/nKtC6/716/

```
div.animate1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #c00;
  -webkit-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: 2s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: No, this is it : http://jsfiddle.net/nKtC6/701/  but i realize my error when i don't put a background on "original", i see the other div pass over :/